# RVest: extract tag content inside a class from a supermarket webpage

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to **scrape** a web with Rvest but I'm stuck and can't find the solution.
I manage to successfully load the page in R and extract the part of the HTML that I want, but I cannot get the data that I want.

The piece of HTML (not real URL) I want to **scrape** is:

```
<a class="open-modal" data-id="53357" href="http://www.website.com.ar/product_1.html">
<img id="prod-image-53357" src="https://www.website.com.ar/media/98989898.jpg"
                           alt="insecticide 360 cc" />
</a>
```

My code:

```
library("rvest")
library("xml2")

url <- "https://www.website.com.ar/limpieza.html"
page <- read_html(url)
d <-page %>% html_nodes(" .open-modal")
```

if I inspect object d, for example d[[4]], I obtain:

```
{html_node}
<a class="open-modal" data-id="53357" href="https://www.website.com.ar/product_1.html">
[1] <img id="prod-image-53357" src="https://www.website.com.ar/media/98989898.jpg
alt="insecticide 360 cc" />
```

And I want to extract href, alt and src as text and convert them as a dataframe...

I have tried:

```
d <-page %>% html_nodes(" .open-modal") %>% html_text()
```

and

```
d <-page %>% html_nodes(" .open-modal") %>% html_text('href')
```

with no success...

Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you should use `html_attr` :

```
library(rvest)
d <- page %>% html_nodes("a.open-modal") 
data.frame(href = d %>% html_attr('href'), 
           alt = d %>% html_attr('alt'),
           src = d %>% html_attr('src'))
```